# Sharepoint online survey permissions

Tags: permissions, survey, online

I created a survey in my sharepoint online site.

If I give contribute permissions the user can add responses but can also edit permissions and add questions to the survey. Also, with contribute permissions, even if I set the survey advanced permissions to "Read responses that were created by the user" insetad of "Read all responses" the user can still see all responses, even the other user responses, he also can edit and delete those answers...

If i give read permissions the user can't respond to the survey...

What can I do?
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone had changed the contribute permissions. 
Solved